# Probability of winning a lot

Tags: probability, gambling

So there's this game that I'm analysing, in which out of $45$ numbered balls ( numbered from $1$ to $45$ ), I choose $8$ balls.

$6$ out of the $45$ balls are drawn in the end of round by the organiser, and who get's $6$ out of $8$ balls of his draws, matching with the winning $6$ drawn balls, he wins the whole round.

my question is what is the probability of drawing those $6$ balls( $6$ winning numbers ), knowing that I drew 8 balls. So as a total we'll have $6$ correct matching balls and $2$ wrong. Order doesn't matter here.

My approach was that we have $6\times5\times4\times3\times2$ ways of drawing those $6$ balls, and $39 C 2$ ways to draw the $2$ wrong balls, over the all possible ways of drawing the $8$ balls out of the $45$ balls.

so my answer is $\frac{6\times5\times4\times3\times2 (39 C 2)}{45 C 8}$

Am I correct doing so ?

Comment: It is far easier to consider the related problem where the organizer doesn't exist and the balls you are hoping to have drawn are very specifically balls numbered $1,2,3,4,5,6$.  Recognize that this scenario will have the same final answer as your original scenario.

Comment: As to your answer, it is very close... however the $6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2$ is unnecessary.  The question of whether order matters or doesn't matter in a particular counting situation commonly gives beginners a problem.  The end result is that it often doesn't matter whether order matters or doesn't matter... you can choose for yourself.  The final answer should be the same either way.  However... you need to be *consistent* with whether or not you treat order as relevant for numerator and denominator.  Your denominator you treated order as irrelevant but not for numerator.

Comment: Kindly correct me if I'm wrong. So in my case, I considered the ordered number of ways to get those 6 winning balls? meanwhile there's only 1 way of getting those 6 balls?

Comment: There are $\binom{45}{8}$ ways of selecting the eight balls you pick where order doesn't matter.  Otherwise there are $45\times 44\times 43\times \cdots \times 38$ ways of selecting the eight balls you pick where order *does* matter.  If we choose to continue counting where order doesn't matter then we consider the *one* way of having picked the six target balls and $\binom{39}{2}$ ways of picking the additional balls where order doesn't matter.  Otherwise if we wanted order *to* matter we would have $6\times 5\times \cdots 2\times 1 \times 39\times 38\times \binom{8}{2}$ ways of picking them

Comment: And that would result in the same answer as you said! Thank you!

Comment: You just need to be consistent.  Whether you chose to write the answer as $\dfrac{\binom{39}{2}}{\binom{45}{8}}$ or if you choose to write the answer as $\dfrac{6!\times 39\times 38\times \binom{8}{2}}{45\times 44\times \cdots \times 38}$, that is up to you, but you need to be *consistent* with your approach, either treating order as relevant for *both* numerator and denominator, or choosing to treat order as *not* relevant for *both* numerator and denominator.  Of course, the calculations are often *much* simpler for order not relevant so that is often what is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for helping again! I'll keep that in mind! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is close to correct. The problem is that you are looking at all orders of choosing the six "correct" balls. Instead, there is only one way to choose all six of the six "correct" balls:

$$\dfrac{({_6C_6})({_{39}C_2})}{ {_{45}C_8} }$$

Comment: Kindly correct me if I'm wrong. So in my case, I considered the ordered number of ways to get those 6 winning balls? meanwhile there's only 1 way of getting those 6 balls?